# AChartEngine max x labels visible

Tags: android, mobile, charts, achartengine

My question is how to set in AChartEngine lots of x labels on x axis and set visible only for example 20 and when make zoom in more precision labels will appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning, just set the needed maximum number of labels for the initial view:

```
renderer.setXLabels(20);
```

Whenever you zoom in, AChartEngine will update the labels to have a maximum number of 20 labels. It automatically chooses the round values labels, so you won't have exactly 20, but you will have a decent number of quite round numbers.

On the other side, if you mean custom text labels, like the ones you add using renderer.setXTextLabel() then you have to listen for zoom events and update the labels accordingly:

```
mChartView.addZoomListener(new ZoomListener() {
  public void zoomApplied(ZoomEvent e) {
    double start = renderer.getXAxisMin();
    double stop = renderer.getXAxisMax();
    double step = (stop - start) / 20;
    renderer.removeXTextLabels();
    for (double i = start; i <= stop; i += step) {
      renderer.addXTextLabel(i, "text");
    }
  }

  public void zoomReset() {
  }
}, true, true);
```

Comment: it works for number labels but doesn't work for Text labels unfortunately :(

Comment: I will try it would propably solve my problem :), there is one little mistake in your code I suppose it should be "double step = (stop-start)/20;" instead of "double step = (start - stop) / 20;".
Thank you very much for help anyway ! :)

Comment: There is one more mistake. It's working but when I move my chart to left or to right there are no XTextLabels.

Comment: You have to listen for pan events as well. mChartView.addPanListener()

Comment: Hi Dan what in mCharview here?

Comment: An instance of GraphicalView.

Comment: Hey dan  renderer.removeXTextLabels(); its giving compile time error... renderer.removeXTextLabels(X); so what i ll give inplace of x..